# How does the Abyssal Armour interact with the "Wolf kill", "Witch kill", and dying because of other reasons?

Tags: werewolv.es

How does the Abyssal Armour (AA) interact with the "Wolf kill", "Witch kill", and dying because of other reasons?

Alternatively, how does night immunity relate to dying because of other reasons than the two mentioned kill types?

Answer (score 1):

The Abyssal Armour grants night immunity to the bearer, in the same way that a role such as a Vampire is night immune. This automatically prevents deaths from normal attacks (e.g. wolfpack kills) once per game attacks (e.g. witch potions) and will prevent roleblocks (e.g. Direwolf) or redirects (e.g. Succubus).

As the bearer is night immune, the armour cannot be destroyed by an attack from another player, although it doesn't stop the item being robbed, or the player being lynched.

Comment: I have the following remaining question: "*Can night immunity stop a player from dying due to role effects other than killing?*"

Some examples: a Messiah using Sacrifice, a Maplewolf starving, a subfaction Leader trying to recruit a Vampire, a Puppet or Zombie (with Abyssal Armour) when the PM/VD dies.

I don't know how these types of deaths are coded, whether the action of killing them can be compared to a type of kill, and thus whether night immunity has any effect on them.

Comment: @Shabas perhaps best to answer the question separately and link it to here if it's related. I don't believe comments are supposed to be used to answer separate questions.

Comment: Alright I'll post a new question for that. It was part of my original question but I guess that didn't come across in the edited version anymore...