# Type of protection granted by Steel Armour and Wolf Pelt

Tags: werewolv.es

What type of protection is offered by the Steel Armour and the Wolf Pelt? Do they confer protection against 'Wolf kills' only, or also against 'Witch kills', and do they offer protection to deaths because of other reasons?

(There is some relation to this question to another question I posted on the Abyssal Armour and night immunity, both are directed at trying to understand the general picture of protective mechanisms and the ways people can die - see [How does the Abyssal Armour interact with the "Wolf kill", "Witch kill", and dying because of other reasons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352670/kill-mechanics-wolf-kill-witch-kill-and-night-immunity))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steel Armour and Wolf Pelts provide the same type of protection. It is non-magical and stops direct "normal attacks". Both will stop

- Any type of wolf kill
- Vampire kill
- Vampire recruit attempt
- Voodoo doctor kill
- Ghoul kill
- Crossbow shot

Steel Armour / Wolf Pelts will NOT stop

- Witch kill
- Militia kill
- Blight activation
- Banshee possession