# Interaction night immunity and role effects (non-kill)

Tags: werewolv.es

(How) does night immunity influence whether people die due to role-related mechanics that are not characterized as a type of kill?

All possible scenario's I can think of, in which the role is made night immune (with Abyssal Armour): a Messiah using Sacrifice, a Maplewolf starving, a subfaction Leader trying to recruit a Wolf/Vampire/Demon, or a Puppet/Zombie when the PM/VD dies.

(Note: this was a subquestion of [How does the Abyssal Armour interact with the "Wolf kill", "Witch kill", and dying because of other reasons?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352670/how-does-the-abyssal-armour-interact-with-the-wolf-kill-witch-kill-and-dyi) which I'm addressing here in a separate question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked all of these situations listed and in each case, the death ignores immunity so they would all happen.

Although there may be a cause to change the failed Mason recruit scenario in the future and make this register an attack against the leader instead, in which case it would follow normal protection, armour and immunity rules.